# Not losing resolution on ios screen snapshot

Tags: ios, objective-c, screenshot

If I set the scale to 2 in the below function when taking a snapshot of a view, will that prevent losing resolution when the image is diSplayed on a larger device such as from iphonE 5 to iphone 6+?

`void UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ( CGSize size, BOOL opaque, CGFloat scale );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and instead of hard-coding it to 2, use `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`.